# Zend pass variable from plugin to view

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

In plugin I try  $this->view->menu = $menu; , but in view I try `<?php var_dump($this->menu); ?`> and get `NULL`

Maybe are solution to pass variable from plugin to view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like below

**First :** Without using helpers or plugins do :

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('whatever', 'foo');
```

After this you can use the following in your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->whatever; ?>
```

This will print "foo".

**OR**

**Second :**

```
<?php

class My_Layout_Plugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
   public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
   {
      $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
      $view = $layout->getView();

      $view->whatever = 'foo';
   }
}
```

then register this plugin with the front controller, e.g.

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new My_Layout_Plugin());
```

Comment: glad to help you @Tomas Lietuva, will please vote up my answer, so if some one has some issue in future they can utilize our thread.